# How to observe an inherited property in Polymer without redefining property

Tags: inheritance, polymer, extends, behavior

How can an inherited property be observed in Polymer without redefining the property? For example, say a behaviour module called `InheritedBehaviour` has a property called `x` and is added to a custom module as per below:

```
<dom-module id="foo-bar">
    <script>
        Polymer({

            is: 'foo-bar',

            behaviors: [
                InheritedBehaviour
            ]

        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

This property can be observed in the following way:

```
<dom-module id="foo-bar">
    <script>
        Polymer({

            is: 'foo-bar',

            behaviors: [
                InheritedBehaviour
            ],

            properties: {
                x: {
                    type: Number,
                    observer: '_doSomething'
                }
            },

            _doSomething: function() {
                console.log('Something!');
            }

        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

However, this 'redefines' the property on this object. So if `InheritedBehaviour` had set `x` to have `reflectToAttribute: true`, this will no longer be set on redefinition (unless it is all rewritten on the new object).

How can inherited properties be extended rather than overridden?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [complex observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#complex-observers) (via the `observers` array in the Polymer object definition) to observe the behavior's property:

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'x-foo',
  behaviors: [InheritedBehavior],
  observers: ['_doSomething(foo)'],
  _doSomething: function(foo) {...}
});
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  let MyBehavior = {
    properties: {
      foo: {
        type: String,
        value: 'hi',
        reflectToAttribute: true
      }
    }
  };
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',

    behaviors: [MyBehavior],

    observers: ['_fooChanged(foo)'],

    _fooChanged: function(foo) {
      console.log('foo', foo);
    },
    _changeFoo: function() {
      const x = ['hey there', 'hello'];
      this.foo = this.foo === x[0] ? x[1] : x[0];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>{{foo}}</div>
      <button on-tap="_changeFoo">Change foo</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VmYePm)

Comment: @WillSquire No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to implement the observer in the Behaviour itself and then override that, something like:

In InheritedBehaviour

```
properties: {
    x: {
        type: Number,
        observer: '_doSomething'
    }
},

doSomething: function() {
    console.log('Designed to be overridden!');
}
```

In foo-bar:

```
doSomething: function() {
    // Here you can do whatever you want to do!
    // This method overrides the one in the behaviour
}
```

I removed the underscore, since this method would no longer be 'private'.